# How could I only deploy a specific module to my remote repository?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, module, remote-repository

I have a Maven project with several modules, but I only want one to be deployed to my remote repository server. I tried to put the `distributionManagement` in the pom of my module that I want to deploy, but it can only be put in the main pom. How could I do this?

Thank you.

Edit: Fixed by putting

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

to the modules that I don't want to be deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by setting the skip property of the maven deploy plugin to true in all other modules.

But: Why is it multi-module project if you only need one of the modules later? Shouldn't it be split up?

Comment: I need all the modules, but only one to be deployed. Anyway, thanks for the solution! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make this module an independent project. Remove parent section from its pom file.